# Nautical terms for shortening or lengthening a rope ~ Translation of ‘cazar’ and ‘filar’

Tags: single-word-requests, nautical-terms

Need equivalents for these two Spanish terms:

> **cazar**
> Tirar y acortar la ‘parte útil’ de un cabo, con el fin de aumentar su tensión.

> **???**
> To pull and shorten gradually the ‘useful portion’ of a rope in order to increase its tension.

> **filar**
> Soltar gradualmente un cabo alargando su ‘parte útil’ con el fin de disminuir su tensión.

> **pay out?** To lengthen gradually a rope increasing its ‘useful portion’ in order to decrease its tension.

At least in Spanish the terms are very versatile, they can be used for the sail ropes as well as the anchor rope, etc. I only could find a supposed equivalent for the second term but not for the first one, I searched ‘pay in’ without any useful result. Would be glad if someone who knows could answer this.

Comment: Did you consider "take in"?

Comment: I'd use tighten, pull tight, or pull taut for the first, but they're not nautical terms. Is it just pulling by hand rather than a ratchet or other mechanism?

Comment: @StuartF The two terms are nautical, but also are *very versatile* in all possible sense, it could be by hand, ratchet or any mechanism

Comment: @Robusto — I don't know about *take in*. I think of that (in sailing anyway) as something you do to a sail. Yes, you use a rope to take in a sail, but you don’t say ”take in the rope”.

Comment: @TinfoilHat And *how* do you say? Note also that in Spanish both terms can be used either to a rope or a sail

Comment: *Pay out* is normally used with respect to a line or chain that is already fairly slack. You might pay out 300 feet of rode before setting the anchor. *Ease* would seem to be a better fit.

Comment: I work with steel wire rope for mechanical automation and we use 'take in' all the time. There are no sails involved.

Comment: Possibly relevant, but rope tension will decrease if you pay out rope if it's forming a catenary. If you pay out rope that is simply hanging downwards then tension at the top will actually *increase* due to increasing the rope's self-mass (unless it's bunching on the ground in which case it's already reached its maximum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [*Glossary of Nautical Terms: English – Spanish / Spanish – English*](https://icdept.cgaux.org/pdf_files/English-Spanish-Glossary-Nautical-Terms.pdf) by the [The United States Coast Guard Auxiliary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Coast_Guard_Auxiliary), *cazar*  means ***to tighten***.

Also there: *filar*/*dar linea* means *pay out (a line)*.

In plain English, we can certainly understand *to tighten* (remove slack from) a rope. But if the captain yells “Reef the main!” — you’re going to need to know quite a bit more than plain English to comply.